# Deploying clojure/java no-web app running in the background to Cloudfoundry

Tags: java, deployment, clojure, cloud-foundry

I have an application in Clojure which I'd like to deploy to CloudFoundry. The application is doing a background job, and needs to run periodically/always. It has no web interface. How can I deploy it to CloudFoundry?

I've found several resources which seem to indicate that it might not be difficult, but I'm not sure how to do it, I don't have yet too deep knowledge with CloudFoundry.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you push the application, either add the `--no-route` argument to `cf push` or set `no-route: true` in your [manifest.yml file](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#no-route).  This bypasses the health check on CF which requires your app to be listening for incoming web requests.

Just be careful that your app continues to run.  If the process exits, then CF will interpret that as your app having crashed.

Comment: Thanks, the `no-route` argument seems to indicate that the application is a worker. I've yet an issue that for some reason it does not start the application. Anyhow, that's a different problem.